# How to remove edge creases?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I've *creased* some edges (applying different values to them) using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. Now I want to ***remove some of them/all of them***. How to do it? I've selected the whole mesh and tried using the *edges specials menu* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), but there are only options for clearing the *seams*, *sharpness* and *freestyle*  (*Clear Seam*, *Clear Sharp*, *Clear Freestyle Edge*). How to 'clear' the creases?
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may remove the edge creases by selecting the whole mesh or only the desired edges,  and then opening the properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd>

Then change the *mean crease* to `0`

[image]

Another way is to press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and enter a negative value (`-1` for instance).

Documentation is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_data.html?#edge-crease)